# Get Primary Key of the table From Combo Box

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm using this method to fetch foreign key from Table Teachers.
Combo box have teachers name. Whenever I changed the selectoin It shows the name of the selected teacher in txtname.Text. But the message box inside while loop is not popping Up.

```
private void cmbTeacher_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Tname = cmbTeacher.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
            con.Open();
            string qbc = "Select TeacherID from Teachers where Name = ' " + Tname + " ' ";
            SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand(qbc, con);
            SqlDataReader drat = cmda.ExecuteReader();
            while (drat.Read())
            {
                textTeacherID.Text = drat[0].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(drat[0].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
            txtname.Text = cmbTeacher.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

**Actually drop down list of Combo box is a column of name from table Teachers. When a user select the teacher from the drop down list I want to fetch the primary key of that teacher. Look at this Code**

```
 // Teacher Table
            con.Open();
            String qt = "Select Name, TeacherID from Teachers";
            SqlCommand cmdt = new SqlCommand(qt, con);
            SqlDataReader drt = cmdt.ExecuteReader();
            while (drt.Read())
            {
                cmbTeacher.Items.Add(drt["Name"].ToString());
                cmbTeacher.DisplayMember = (drt["Name"].ToString());
                cmbTeacher.ValueMember = (drt["TeacherID"].ToString());
                cmbTeacher.Text = "Select Teacher";

            }
            con.Close();
```

How Can I get the primary key of that Teacher???

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning a result? If `drat.Read()` never returns true that means the query didn't return any rows. (Also, concatenating strings to create SQL queries introduces the risk of SQL injection.)

Comment: why is the query using a random variable called `Tname` and not `cmdTeacher.SelectionItem.ToString()`

Comment: cmbTeacher.SelectedItem is not working

Comment: Name = ' " + Tname + " '  Don't do that. use bind variables

Comment: Thanks @BryanDellinger
Using bind variables did the Job.